# can we quantize a static electron-magnetic vector potential which is time-independent?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I am thinking since a static vector potential which is time-independent do not have dynamics (such as in Cylindrical coordinate **A**(ρ, φ, z)=1/ρ) , how can we quantize it? since I know the photons have dynamics and can propagate, quantize such time-independent vector field will not give rise photons! or my question is: is every classical field that satisfy maxwell equations quantizable in principle (some of the solutions for vector potentials is static, such as (φ(r)=0,**A**(**r**)), or some of them can only be treated as classical background field?

Comment: Nothing in the usual quantization of the electromagnetic field presupposes a particular form. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: What happens to a resting charge in a static magnetic field? What would happen to it, if there were (on average) propagating photons?

Comment: May be the question don't bring it to the point, but it seems to be reasonable to ask about quantisation and possible constituents behind the quantisation.

Comment: Real photons can only be emitted by accelerating charges but virtual photons do not have this restriction. A time independant electromagnetic field can be described by QED just like any other electromagnetic field.

Answer (score 2):

If $\mathbf{A}$ does not depend on time it follows from Maxwell's equations
that, excluding a linear growth of $\mathbf{E}$ in time, that it is also
time-independent. We can try to quantise $\mathbf{A}$,

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{A(x)=}\sum_{j}\int d\mathbf{k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}}\{a_{\mathbf{k}%
j}^{\ast }\mathbf{\bar{u}}_{\mathbf{k}j}(\mathbf{x})+a_{\mathbf{k}j}\mathbf{u%
}_{\mathbf{k}j}(\mathbf{x})\}\mathbf{,}
\end{equation*}
where, in the Coulomb gauge,
\begin{equation*}
\partial _{\mathbf{x}}^{2}\mathbf{u}_{\mathbf{k}j}(\mathbf{x})=0
\end{equation*}
but I see no possibility to obtain a quantised version of $\mathbf{E}$ from
this.